# Trying to automate clip for multiple polygons based on unique field ID?

Tags: arcpy, clip, cursor, loop

I have two feature classes, one that contains all counties for 5 states and the other contains 90 polygons I need clipped only to their pertaining county boundary, but they overlap/ cross the county boundary (See image below).  Both feature classes have a field with a unique 5 digit ID for each county as well. Being that I am relatively new to Python, is there a way I can use a loop or searchcursor to clip each of the 90 polygons to their respective county boundary using their 5 digit ID?

*The red rose colored polygons show the overlapping polygons I need to clip and the tan colored polygons show what I need the final product to look like.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you looked into [Make Feature Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) with a `where_clause`? Iterate over each 5-digit id and pass that to MFL on the red and tan layers, clipping as you go.

Comment: You can intersect both datasets and select ones with same id